# ruby daemon script stop when logout ssh

Tags: ruby, linux

I'm developing a ruby script that open a port, I'm using daemon gem and it is working well, but when I logout from ssh the process id killed, how can I made that this script keep running after close my ssh session?

#### Environment

- Ubuntu 12.04
- Ruby 1.9.3
- Amazon ec2
- Event machine Gem
- Daemons Gem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based in my post, I'm using daemons gem, so I can control my script in the correct way, the problem was when I started the daemon `ruby daemon.rb start` the process owner was my ssh user, so my solution was change the user and group of my file

```
sudo chown root daemon.rb
sudo chgpr root daemon.rb
```

Now, in order to run the script, it have to be started by root user, so my script is alive after exit ssh session

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nohup` command.  It stands for 'no hangup'.  Try doing

`nohup ruby whatever.rb &`

Comment: There is not a cleaner way? can I control the daemon if I run it as you suggest?

Comment: You can bring it back into the foreground with the `fg` command.

Comment: Now I using a cleaner solution